# Top navigation link in Magento that I can't get rid of

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, theming

I'm working on a new theme for an existing Magento installation, and I've got a rogue link.  The last guy apparently decided to hard code a link to the AW Blog extension he was using in the top navigation.  See here:  derm2go.com - link is "articles".  I'm getting rid of AW Blog in favor of an integrated wordpress install, but when I uninstall AW Blog, the site breaks (everything after the nav dissapears) and I get this error in my logs:

> 2011-11-19T08:56:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'Mage/Blog/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/chroot/home/dermtwog/derm2go.com/html/app/code/local:/chroot/home/dermtwog/derm2go.com/html/app/code/community:/chroot/home/dermtwog/derm2go.com/html/app/code/core:/chroot/home/dermtwog/derm2go.com/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /chroot/home/dermtwog/derm2go.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on
>   line 93

I've searched everywhere, I can think of that might effect the nav menu, and I don't know where the link is coming from - it's not in the CMS/static blocks, its not in any of the default template files on the server (I deleted and reinstalled all of them) and it's showing up even when I change templates, so it's probably not in on the sub themes.

Does anyone out there know of other files it could be hiding in?  I'm assuming the last guy did a quick and dirty hack somehow - and maybe messed with core files?  Would really rather not have to do a full reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

The uninstall may have not worked properly and left files behind that are still being called. Go to /app/etc/modules/ and delete AW_Blog.xml if it is still there.
Also make sure that you clear the site's cache afterwards.

Comment: Tried that - module is gone and and cleared the cache - nothing worked.  To keep my site up, have to keep AW Blog installed.  Problem is the previous developer did something strange to change the label on the link in the menu - the normal implementation of the AW Blog lets you choose the name of the blog in the settings, and control wether its in the nav.  On this site, you can change the name of the blog, but the link still reads "articles".  Even if you disable the blog, the link stays.  Says to me that there's a hard coded link somewhere in one of the phtml or layout files.

Comment: The file that loads the dynamic links in the menu is template/page/template/links.phtml . See if that's been edited (compare your theme to the base theme). If that file isn't being loaded check in template/page/html/header.phtml to see how the navigation is being created.
If it is loaded and hasn't been edited to hardcode the link in, check in your theme's layout folder for .xml files that could be adding in the link (e.g. aw_blog.xml, or if it was manually added in try page.xml or local.xml).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - ended up finding a weird set of codes in one of the child themes in top.phtml.  Was propagating through the whole site - thank you!